# Add Where Clause to OleDbCommand

Tags: sql, vb.net

Is there a way to add a a SQL Where clause to this line of code?

Sorry, should have put more detail into this question. This line of code is connecting to a SQL Database and exporting a select statement to a csv file. If i put in a where clause as you would normally do in a SQL query it gives me the error, In operator without () in query expression 'ID = '1' IN ''{ODBC:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}.

```vb
dpConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ExportDir & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;"""

Dim dpTextConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(dpConnectionString)
dpTextConnection.Open()

Try
    Dim dpTextCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO ["test.txt"] FROM [csv_SavedCalData] WHERE ID = '1' IN '' [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=" & sqlServer & ";Database=" & sqlDatabase & ";UID=" & sqlUN & ";PWD=" & sqlPWD & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;]", dpTextConnection)
    dpTextCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dpTextCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dpTextCommand.Dispose()
    dpTextConnection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: That is a mess.  Use SQL Paramters, and the second argument is supposed to be an OleDbConnection, not a connection string.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder what happens if I set `My.Settings.txtServer` to `A;DROP TABLE csv_SavedCalData;`... _- I don't even know if that's proper SQL :]_, but it can be exploited either way. So, parameters.

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying SQL and having "SQL Server Native Client 11.0", I would assume your questions is about exporting an SQL server table's content to a CSV file. Your codes wouldn't work, you cannot select into a text file from an SQL server table. There are many ways to work around the issue in VB.Net. One simple way is to use Linq to CSV from codeplex. Or for a simple schema you could directly use file writing functions. ie: Using Northwind sample database, output a few fields from Customers table:

```
Sub Main
    Using con = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLexpress;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind")
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("Select CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Phone,Fax,Address,City,PostalCode,Region,Country from Customers", con)
            Using sw = New StreamWriter("c:\Temp\MyCustomerData.csv", False, Encoding.Default)
                sw.WriteLine("CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Phone,Fax,Address,City,PostalCode,Region,Country")

                con.Open()
                Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdr.Read()
                    sw.WriteLine("""{0}"",""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}"",""{4}"",""{5}"",""{6}"",""{7}"",""{8}"",""{9}"",""{10}""", _
                        rdr("CustomerID"), rdr("CompanyName"), rdr("ContactName"), rdr("ContactTitle"), rdr("Phone"), _
                        rdr("Fax"), rdr("Address"), rdr("City"), rdr("PostalCode"), rdr("Region"), rdr("Country"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This will work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You include it the same way you included your SELECT and FROM clauses... in the string, in the correct place

Example Syntax: (From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp))

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Code Sample:

```
"SELECT * INTO [" & certExportFile & "] FROM [csv_SavedCalData] WHERE [ColumnName] IN ''
```

And, as Plutonix said, that is a mess. I would suggest [reading up on SQL parameters in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)